# Error while create a new react-native project

Tags: android-studio, react-native, npm-start

Trying to create a new app on react-native. 'react-native start' command gives no error. But I'm not able to see my app on the emulator. Can anyone help me in figuring out the problem. I'm new to react-native.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a Macbook or Windows? For Windows, you will have to use an Android emulator, thus you will need to download Android Studio, and the Android SDK.

For Mac, you will use the IOS emulator, you will need to download Expo in that case.

Also you could try using the create-react-native-app instead. I built a project with 3 other buddies in two weeks, we found that it had the most reliable boilerplate and is really good for beginning with react-native.

*** Edit:

*** Big caveat with create-react-native-app is that it won't matter what OS your computer has. If you have an apple phone, you just run "npm run ios" then scan the QR code with expo. If you have an Android phone like I had...you will run into a few issues where you need to set the phone to USB debugging mode in the developer's settings, download the USB debugging driver for your phone's model, ensure both your phone and computer are on the same wifi network, install expo, and finally be able to run "npm run android".

I was the only one on my team developing with an Android phone, so if you need advice on that, feel free to ask.

- Some extra information about *create-react-native-app* is that it allows you to code for both Android and IOS phones by using the same project folder, rather than having to adjust settings for one platform at a time.

That has it's pros and cons for sure and there will be little differences in how one platform functions over the other...so my recommendation is to build for one platform at a time, focusing on whichever one you are testing on.

Since you're using Ubuntu

Getting started with create-react-native-app:

https://github.com/react-community/create-react-native-app

Starting Guide for Setting up the Emulator or App Environment on phone:

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html

Comment: Can you provide more info on  create-react-native-app? because it is the best for beginners ;)

Comment: I'm am using Ubuntu. I have the emulator running. But I am not able to see my app on the emulator. @MisterSnow Can you please elaborate more on create-react-native-app. Thank you

Comment: I just added more information. Apologies for being vague lol. But yeah hopefully that information helps, and feel free to ask me more questions about react-native or creact (create-react-native-app) as we like to call it.

Comment: @MisterSnow Thanks alot. create-react-native-app worked for me :) Yes, If i have any more doubts will surely ask you. Thanks.